# iOS "specialized" TableView Crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I am getting this crash report in Xcode from a little application I am currently running. When I open the crash in the project I do not get anymore information made available to me.

My cellForRowAt function is below. This is my first iOS application and I am not sure what is causing this crash. The crash seems to be very intermittent. The application can hours or even days without crashing and then will suddenly crash, usually while in the background.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! eventTableCell

            let eventData = LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[indexPath.row]
            let approval = eventData.approved
            if approval == false {
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unapproved")
            }
            else {
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "approved")
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[indexPath.row].customer)   \(secondsToHoursMinutesString(seconds: Int(LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray[indexPath.row].duration * 60)))"
        return cell
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var eventData:Int
    print ( LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count)
    if LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count == 0 {
        eventData = 0
       notifyTableIsEmpty()

    } else {
        notifyTableNotEmpty()
        eventData = LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count
    }
    return eventData
}
```

Table cell class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class eventTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerTime: UILabel!

    }
```

Comment: Although `as!` is very dangerous, probably your problem is elsewhere. I would make sure `eventLogArray` would get me the desired element. Can you show number of rows in section method?

Comment: Could you add an exception breakpoint and run again, it would stop at the line that causes the crash

Comment: It's hard to say without more context and it's almost certainly not the `as!` since that would be very obvious. But, I would like to suggest a small improvement to your code: in generating your string for the label, you already have the event data available so it could look like this instead `"\(eventData.customer)   \(secondsToHoursMinutesString(seconds: Int(eventData.duration * 60)))"`

Comment: I added the number of rows method to my post. Is there a way to create an exception handler in the code itself? This generally doesn't happen for several hours after the app has been running

Comment: ```let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! eventTableCell``` 
in this line `eventTableCell` is an object of a class or the class itself

Comment: EventTableCell is a class it’s self. It is declared in a separate file. I can post that as well if it helps

Comment: Please post it. It may help

Comment: Ok this is becoming interesting. Since your row count is equal to array count, array isn't responsible for the crash. Btw simply `return LocationService.locationInstance.eventLogArray.count` is sufficient there. So we go back to `as!`

Comment: `eventTableCell` this is suspicious as well as stated above. Make sure it is the class name not some instance variable.

Comment: I have added the eventTableCell class code to my question. Thank you everyone for your interest in helping. Hope we can figure it out!

Comment: Some functions run in async. Maybe LocationService runs like this !

Comment: The LocationService does have async functions. There are geocoding functions and Firestore functions going on there but I do not notify the table to update until after appending to the array.